# Openshift online - no longer running collectstatic

Tags: django, openshift, python-3.6, openshift-3

I've got 2 Python 3.6 pods currently running. They both used to run collectstatic upon redeployment, but then one wasn't working properly, so I deleted it and made a new 3.6 pod. Everything is working perfectly with it, except it no longer is running collectstatic on redeployment (so I'm doing it manually). Any thoughts on how I can get it running again?

I checked the documentation, and for the 3.11 version of openshift still looks like it has a variable to disable collectstatic (which i haven't done), but the 4.* versions don't seem to have it. Don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Edit:

So it turns out that I had also updated the django version to 2.2.7. 
As it happens, the openshift infrastructure on openshift online is happy to collectstatic w/ version 2.1.15 of Django, but not 2.2.7 (or 2.2.9). I'm not quite sure why that is yet. Still looking in to it.

Comment: At this time, I'm still going through the support channels trying to figure out why this is the case. I'll update if I find out anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Openshift Online's python 3.6 module doesn't support Django 2.2.7 or 2.2.9.